# Why does "$$" not change in a bash pipeline? Don't they start subprocesses?

Tags: bash, shell, process

I ran following code :

```
echo $$
# Output : 3911
true | while true; do
    eval 'echo $$'
    break
done
# Output : 3911
```

The documentation says that while loop (involved in pipe) runs in a subprocess, in that case, should the two process ids be different ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The value of `$$` in `bash` will stay the same even if you're examining it in a subshell.  This behavior is mandated by [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02):

> `$`
>
> Expands to the decimal process ID of the invoked shell. In a subshell [...], `$` shall expand to the same value as that of the current shell.

You should probably be using `$BASHPID` instead. The following is from the `bash` manual:

> `BASHPID`
>
> Expands to the process ID of the current bash process.  **This
> differs from `$$` under certain circumstances, such as subshells
> that do not require bash to be re-initialized.**  Assignments to
> `BASHPID` have no effect.  If `BASHPID` is unset, it loses its
> special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

Rewriting your code to use `$BASHPID` instead:

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$BASHPID"
true | while true; do
    printf '%s\n' "$BASHPID"
    break
done
```

Running this will output two different PIDs.